# Alter the Main WP_Comment_Query (comments at the bottom of posts)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My plugin retrieves a few comments at the beginning of the post through my own WP_Comment_Query. I save these IDs so I can then alter the WP_Comment_Query request and not fetch these IDs.

When I use the **pre_get_comments** hook to hide these already-fetched IDs, they are also hidden from my first query at the beginning of each post. It defies the point.

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'pre_get_comments', $plugin_public, 'hide_the_comments' );

public function hide_the_comments( $comment_query ) {

    $comment_query->query_vars['comment__not_in'] = $the_ids_to_hide;
}
```

How can we target the bottom request only, just like there is is_main_query() for the post loop?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a private variable, eg `private $count = 0;`
- Increment it each time your function is run
- Don't hide the comments if it's the first time you're running it :)

Comment: could work, but I run an unpredictable number of wp_comment_query. I've change my method and instead of using pre_ hook, I just used the comment_template hook and ran my very own query with very own layout and all.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to target the "main" `WP_Query_Comments()` within the `comments_template()` core function, then the  `comments_template_query_args`  filter is [available](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b5718124c3d4b4078195df6a437bcc82efe7ed0f/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1362-1386) since WordPress 4.5:

```
$comment_args = apply_filters( 'comments_template_query_args', $comment_args );
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $comment_args );
```

See ticket [#34442](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34442) for more info and a simple example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/224290/26350).