# How to filter comments in a post by a certain comment meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filtering

I'm trying to make the comments list in wordpress posts so that they will only list comments with a certain **meta_key** and **meta_value**. So far, I've tried finding answers on google and only found out how to assign a meta key/value when someone adds a comment in the comments form.

in the theme's **functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'comment_post', function($comment_id) {
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, $my_meta_key, $my_meta_value );
});
```

Now what I can't figure out is, how do I make the wordpress posts filter the comments so they only list comments with the certain meta key and value I want them to.

I've made my theme using underscores and I list the comments inside comments.php using the **wp_list_comments()** function.

Comment: Are you calling the `comments_template()` function from your theme?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling comments_template() from single.php and page.php as well.

Comment: Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37099476/2078474) might help.

Comment: Sorry but after I tried reading on the url I still don't get how to filter the comments to only list those with certain comment meta key and value. May I ask for further explanation?

Comment: Did you check out the example link, I mentioned in that answer? It contains a basic usage.

Comment: Yes. I saw about the code

$comment_args = apply_filters( 'comments_template_query_args', $comment_args );
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $comment_args );

though I don't have the idea how to use it and where to put it. Sorry that I'm kind of  new to this and just started to try making a custom theme from _s.

Comment: I'm getting the idea that I need to fiddle the WP_Query_Comments() though I still don't know anything about it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example how to modify the *main comment query*, in `comments_template()`, through the `comments_template_query_args` filter (available for WordPress versions 4.5+):

```
/**
 * Filter non-threaded comments by comment meta, in the (main) comments template
 */
add_filter( 'comments_template_query_args', function( $comment_args )
{
    // Only modify non-threaded comments
    if(    isset( $comment_args['hierarchical'] ) 
        && 'threaded' === $comment_args['hierarchical'] 
    )
        return $comment_args;

    // Our modifications
    $comment_args['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key'     => 'some_key',
            'value'   => 'some_value',
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ];        

    return $comment_args;
} );
```

where you adjust the *meta query* to your needs. Note that this example assumes *PHP 5.4+*.

Comment: I tried using the sample above but I end up getting error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$comment_args' (T_VARIABLE) in <some_dir>....

I'm using xamppp for windows with PHP version 5.6.3 and the error states the line where    $comment_args['meta_query'] = [     is. I wonder what went wrong?

EDIT: I just tried fixing the code format and it's not getting an error now. I'll be back after trying the code.

Comment: ps: this is untested, I just noticed a missing ; (I updated the answer).

Comment: Thanks. I'm back to say that this worked well as I intended it to.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you  @58YtQ2H83m17838963l61BU07Y8622